# How to view user created table in OracleDB?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle19c, tablespace

So I created a table in my OracleDB, however when I use the command to view all tables in my environment, it gives a bunch of other tables, scrolling and filling my command prompt with lot of other tables.

Is there any other command to view just the tables that I created?

This is what I am doing currently

```
C:\> set ORACLE_SID=ocptech;
C:\> sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> CREATE TABLE customers  
     ( customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,  
       customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,  
       city varchar2(50)  
     );  
SQL> SELECT table_name
     FROM user_tables
     ORDER BY table_name;
```

The above command gives me a lot of tables.

Also can someone also explain me, what these tablespace are while executing the following command

```
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME FROM DBA_TABLESPACES
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting as `SYS` user:

```
C:\> sqlplus / as sysdba
```

So you see all tables of SYS user.
Do not use this schema for own objects and tables!
Create your own schema and use it for own objects

Comment: Are schema and user the same thing? Also how do I make the new user access those sys tables?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Create a user, connect as that user, create your tables. It's like user accounts in Linux, if that helps, and you're connecting as root.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding table name, You can use the following query -

```
SELECT table_name
  FROM user_tables
 WHERE table_name = 'customers'
 ORDER BY table_name;
```

For tablespace, this is the storage mechanism of oracle to store the data at the physical level. The smallest unit of storage is data blocks and then segments, the extents, and then tablespace comes into existence.

You can follow the below links for more details.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/physical.htm

Comment: What if there are 100 of user created tables, how do I view in that case of course I can't filter by table name in that case

Comment: The data dictionary provides 3 levels of _tables. *User_Tables*: shows all tables within a user (schema). *All_Tables*: Shows tables which the user (schema) can view.  *DBA_Tables*: Shows all tables in the database. Which level you query you get them every table unless you filter with the **where** clause.

Comment: Surely the OP created a table named `'CUSTOMERS'`, not `'customers'`? And why would you order one row anyway?